# @OneToMany with foreign key as primary

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to do smth like that:

[image]

I have problem because when I want to use OneToMany and save ClassA with some set - I just cant save in repo.

Problem: In table ClassB -> classAId as @ID is null.

**How to save ClassA and automatically create ClassB with primary key of ClassA and userId added to set?**

Answer (score 0):

Model A:

```
@Entity
public class ClassA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Set<Long> userIds = new HashSet<Long>();

    // getters, setters...
}
```

Model B:

```
@Entity
public class ClassB {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String userId;

    // getters, setters...
}
```

Controller B:

```
@PostMapping
public ClassB save(@RequestBody ClassB classB) {
    return classBService.save(classB);
}
```

Service A:

```
public ClassA save(ClassA classA) {
    return classARepo.save(classA);
}
```

Service B:

```
public ClassB save(ClassB classB) {
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    classA.getIds().add(classB.getUserId());
    classB.setId(classAService.save(classA));
    return classARepo.save(classB);
}
```

Comment: @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    private Set<User> users;
.
.
When I create User and add to this class and save, I getting hibernate error: ConstraintViolationException. Why hibernate cant just add Id to the children of OneToMany ?